# How to process url from user input?

Tags: uri, 8

I am creating **LinkedImage** field, formatter and widget so that images can be linked to somewhere.

And I have an issue with the input. The user can set internal or external links like `/node/1`, `<front>` or `http://www.google.com`. But the `Url` object that is required for link render element has no method that would work with all of these.

The `Url::fromUserInput` will work with internal paths but not with `<front>`. The `Url::fromUri()` will work with `http://www.google.com` but not with `<front>` or `/node/1`.

So I had to implement logic to distinguish the format and also I had to add validation handler into the widget telling the user that the link has to start with forward slash or with http prefix.

But I do not like this approach. Seems like this is not how it is supposed to be done.

So how can I properly construct `Url` object from these three types of input?

Also another issue here is that if "malformed" URL is already set (ie. it hasn't been validated via my UI validation handler) then I will get WSOD and that is just really bad UX.

Plus, as you can see, `<front>` is not working with any of these methods whic hrequires additional logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, so please try this:

```
$url_object = \Drupal::service('path.validator')->getUrlIfValid($path);
$url_object->setAbsolute();
$url = $url_object->toString();
```

Comment: Seems to be working. Although links starting with www instead of http will return false. But I'm fine with that + I am using textfield ant not url since it does not work with internal paths ans so i have custom validation handler in place which ca ntake care of this.

Comment: what if :Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default, use \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse for it.